# Can't downgrade to a specific version of "android gradle plugin version"

Tags: android-studio, gradle

[image]

Android Gradle Plugin is greyed out and I can't change it.

I am using Hedgehog android studio version.

build.gradle -> project level

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
}
```

build.gradle -> module level:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.masala_food_recipes'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.masala_food_recipes"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Is any thing here I can change? or Am I changing something else?

Comment: Drop here your project level build.gradle

Comment: Done checkout the question.

Comment: You can downgrade your gradle version to the specific version from `gradle/wrapper
/gradle-wrapper.properties` file by changing the `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip` line to
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-[YOUR-VERSION]-bin.zip` and sync changes.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following, which worked for me:

After setting the Gradle version to your desired version, set the version for the plugins `com.android.application` and `com.android.library` as given in https://developer.android.com/build/releases/gradle-plugin#groovy (Gradle version section).

In your case, 7.4.0.